# without remove overflow hidden how can i show div box?

Tags: jquery, css, html

This is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.caption').hide();
    $('.replaybox', this).hover(function () {
        $('.caption', this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: 30
        }, 200);
    }, function () {
        $('.caption', this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0,
            height: 0
        }, 200);
    });

    $('span').click(function () {
        $('.div', this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Now what I want when my mouse hover on `.replaybox` so `.caption` div height is animate 30px. And I put the span in the `.caption` Class now when I click on span so `.div` class is toggle and that time `.replaybox` overflow is hidden so my `.div` box is hidden in main class so how can I show on top with height and with.
HTML code is hare:

```
<div class="replaybox">
    <div class="caption"> 
         <span>
                <img src="coffe.png"/>
                <div class="div"></div>
         </span>
         <span>
                <img src="emotion.png"/>
                <div class="div"></div>
         </span>
         <span>
                <img src="podcast.png"/>
                <div class="div"></div>
              </span>
         <span>
                <img src="cog.png"/>
                <div class="div"></div>
         </span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

you can also see in this link:
 http://jsfiddle.net/Abhinav/yYW9C/7/

Comment: Hi @user, welcome to SO.  A backtick ` will do inline code.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle of your link](http://jsfiddle.net/yYW9C/9/)

you added a hide now you need to show()

```
$(function(){

        $('.caption').hide();
        $('.replaybox').hover(function(){

            $('.caption',this).show(50).animate({opacity: 1,
            height: 30}, 200);
        },function(){

                $('.caption',this).animate({opacity: 0,
            height: 0 }, 200);


        });

        $('span').click(function(){

            $('.div',this).slideToggle();

        });  
});
```